# Female warrior who blacks out & slaughters friends | Mage working spells like beads on a thread | Shadow thorn creature tormenting town]

Tags: story-identification, books

Apologies for the long title and likely to be sparse details. I remember reading this book about 15-20 years ago but for the life of my I cannot remember it's name and only patches of what the book was about. I weirdly had a dream about it the other day and have been racking my brain trying to find the book!

- Classic 1980/90's sword and sorcery book. There is an evil that must be defeated (and for the life of me I can't remember if it was a person, thing, dark tower, big black orb etc). I think it's maybe an evil sorcerer?
- There is a female warrior/paladin with him who's history in the past was that she tried to defeat the big bad with a group, and she blacked out and slaughtered most of the the group before she regained consciousness. Now she's struggling with going back again to fight it.
- The main protagonist of the book is a mage/wizard who works spells by imagining them as beads on a thread within a tapestry in his mind which was his version of a grimoire. Has to really concentrate to prepare before using any. He's not the most charismatic of characters
- Part of the plot involves the mage/wizard being recruited to clear out a 'curse' on a towns well and then finds out there is some shadow/invisible big thorny evil that he has to fight which has been plaguing the town.

That is about all I remember and I'm really hoping someone here might have read it too.

Comment: This sounds very familiar, but I haven't quite placed it yet.

Comment: If it comes to you, please do let me know. Its literally been bugging me for too long. I am almost certain it was a novella and not part of a series. There is also this nagging feeling that there was some romantic undertones between the two characters (paladin and magician)